# How to change page on button click of webview windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

What I am trying to do is have a webview on the blank page generated by a template for the Windows Store. Then when I click a button, it changes the page that the webview is currently on. The problem is, I do not know how to access the XAML variable from the codebehind to change it.

```
<Page
x:Class="App6.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App6"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="browser"  Source="https://www.google.com/" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="463,237,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="570"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="224,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

I've tried accessing the name browser in the C# code. But Visual Studio can't find it. I've looked around for a little bit but there weren't many examples that I could find that had this.... 
I've tried to open this (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) for an example of how to use it. But this will not build, or open with Visual Studio 2013..

code behind it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?           LinkId=234238

namespace App6
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what your codebehind file looks like?

Comment: @laptou added code, there's not much here. not to sure how to work with xaml..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   browser.Navigate(new Uri(@"www.microsoft.com"));
}
```

Where `browser` is your actual control `WebView`.

Comment: i've tried that, but all that happens is this "name 'browser' does not exist in the current context" it is not seeing the xaml variables...

Comment: @MichaelLapan Did you try rebuilding it? No error in MainPage.app.g.cs?

Comment: yes im tried to, still the same error. but i do get this error "'App6.MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' and no extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'App6.MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)". but i can run the program fine...

Comment: @MichaelLapan What's the filename? MainPage?

Comment: This is somewhat foreign to me because I haven't used codebehinds at all for a long time. I _always_ use MVVM when coding a XAML/C# project.

Comment: @MichaelLapan Try deleting the file again and create a blank page with MainPage as its name. See if the error still exists.

Comment: @laptou i swear i get the stranges of visual studios bugs... after restarting, cleaning and rebuilding it. and then restarting again it worked... also ill have to look up MVVM could you link me to any thing good?

Comment: @MichaelLapan Start here http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-phone-8-development-for-absolute-beginners